# Proof by induction that $3^{3n}+1$ Is divisible by 7

Tags: analysis

How to proof by induction that

$3^{3n}+1$ Is divisible by 7 for all odd n>=1?

First step:

n=1 it Is clearly true

Now suppose that for a certain k Is true

$3^{3\cdot (2\cdot k+1)}+1=7\cdot a$

The goal Is to proof that

also

$3^{6\cdot k+9}+1$ Is multiple of 7.

Is that correct and how to complete the proof?

I try ti complete the proof:

By the induction hyoothesis I know that

$3^{6\cdot k+3}=7a-1$

So $3^6\cdot (7a-1)+1=7b-728$ which Is clearly a multiple of 7.
This completes the proof?

Comment: If we go deeper into algebra, we can think numbers in modulus $7$. In our case $3^3 = 27 \equiv -1 (\mod 7)$ so we know $(-1)^n + 1 \equiv 0 (\mod 7)$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Why does the tag say "analysis" here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The induction hypothesis tells you that $3^{6k+3}=7a-1$ and $3^{6k+9} = 3^6\cdot 3^{6k+3}$ so ...

Comment: @@jjagmath so because $3^6-1$ Is 728 divisible by 7 follows the proof?

Comment: Yes, that is actually the point. Since $3^6-1$ is multiple of $7$, then using inductio hypothesis, $3^{2k+3}$ too

Answer (score 0):

After you checked that it is true for $n=1$, assume it is also true for $n$ equals an odd integer, say, $n=k$, and check whether it is true for the next odd integer $n=k+2$.

For the next odd integer $n=k+2$,

$3^{3n}+1=3^{3(k+2)}+1=3^6\times 3^{3k}+3^6-(3^6-1)=3^6\times (3^{3k}+1)-728$.

Since we already assume $(3^{3k}+1)$ is a multiple of $7$, while $728=104\times 7$, so for the next odd integer $n=k+2$, it is also a multiple of $7$.

Comment: You don't need to calculate $3^6 - 1$. Instead use $3^6 - 1 = (3^3 + 1)(3^3 - 1) = 28 \times 26$ to see that it is a multiple of $7$.